# How to set overflow hidden on React Spring Parallax 'pages'

Tags: css, reactjs, parallax, react-spring

I am using React Spring Parallax (https://www.react-spring.io/docs/props/parallax) in my project here: https://codesandbox.io/s/parallax-sticky-scroll-2zd58?file=/src/App.js

When you click the button to go to the next section, you can see the image is overflowing to the next section. but since react spring sets everything to position absolute I am unable to set each section to overflow hidden.

Is there any way to set overflow hidden to contain my content to each section?

Answer (score 1):

You can easily achieve it by addding following css into styles.css file

```css
html,
body,
#root {
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

Here you can find my forked version of your example
 [Sandbox link](https://codesandbox.io/s/parallax-sticky-scroll-forked-vl559)